# Facebook PHP SDK Sample not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been creating my first App for Facebook, and one of the code samples doesn't seem to be working. I've got the latest PHP SDK:
this php and html code below

My code:

```
<?php
require("facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php");
$app_id = "257964450938655";
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode("http://apps.facebook.com/orangepicker/") . "&scope=email";
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($_encoded_sig, $_payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$_data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($_payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Orange Picker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if (empty($data["user_id"])):
            echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
            echo("<div align=\"center\"><a href=\"" . $auth_url . "\" target=\"blank\">Authorize This Application</a></div>");
            echo($data["user_id"]);?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <noscript><div align="center">You need JavaScript enabled to use this app.</div></noscript>
        <div align="center"><img src="Resources/tree.png" usemap="#treemap" /></div>
        <map name="treemap">
            <area shape="circle" coords="22,29,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="37,26,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="55,22,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="75,14,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="93,16,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="112,13,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="128,12,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="146,17,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="166,26,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="182,33,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="194,42,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="208,57,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="222,70,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="234,88,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="236,110,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="223,123,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="208,134,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="193,146,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="177,155,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="161,165,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="144,171,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="125,171,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="106,166,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="84,162,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="70,158,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="55,151,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="42,136,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="29,123,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="20,107,10" onclick="OrangeClick()" alt="Orange" />
        </map>
        <div align="center" style="font-size:large;"><span id="waitTime"></span> <span id="TotalOranges"></span> <span id="TotalCarts"></span></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function OrangeClick() {

            }
        </script>
        <div align="center">Copyright&#169; Neil Flodin <?php echo date("Y"); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Facebook Sample Code (From [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth)):

```
<?php 

     $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

My code just constantly refreshes the page when I run it. Anybody with FB PHP SDK experience know why?

Comment: Always the small things... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas url (redirect_uri) should be pointing towards where you host the application, and not to the facebook url. I.e the same url that you have added in the facebook developer settings for the canvas!

And also, this line:

```
$_data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($_payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
```

Should be without the underscore:

```
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($_payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
```

Sins you later check the content of `$data` to see if the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have defined the variable as `$_data` when setting it but refereed to it as `$data` when checking it with `empty()`. Since this will cause it to always return true, your code will always output the JavaScript redirect.

I'm guessing you've also previously authenticated the aplication. Which means once you are redirected to Facebook, you are instantly redirected back (since you have already logged in). Thus, infinite loop.

Note:

- You shouldn't put underscores after the `$` or it could be confused
  with one of PHP's special variables.
- You should revise up on [Facebook's PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) documentation. It
  seems a lot of the examples floating around are not for the latest
  version of their SDK.